# Windows Commands

Tags: windows, command

I have this problem, can't find it anywhere. For example, the active or add command from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/add
appears here, but I get the error "'add' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." I'm trying to find a solution, but I don't know where I can find instructions to install these commands.

help with windows command